# ESLint is not recognizing "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-eslint

I have been trying to get ESLint to work on a new Angular project in VS Code but it is failing to load "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin". I have spent the last 3 hours trying to figure out where the problem is and looked everywhere for a solution.

```
Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in 'png-ui/.eslintrc.js': Cannot find module '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'
Require stack:
- /Users/Yahia/Desktop/Plugngrow-UI/__placeholder__.js
Referenced from: /Users/Yahia/Desktop/Plugngrow-UI/png-ui/.eslintrc.js
Happened while validating /Users/Yahia/Desktop/Plugngrow-UI/png-ui/.eslintrc.js
This can happen for a couple of reasons:
1. The plugin name is spelled incorrectly in an ESLint configuration file (e.g. .eslintrc).
2. If ESLint is installed globally, then make sure '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin' is installed globally as well.
3. If ESLint is installed locally, then '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin' isn't installed correctly.

Consider running eslint --debug /Users/Yahia/Desktop/Plugngrow-UI/png-ui/.eslintrc.js from a terminal to obtain a trace about the configuration files used.
```

Debugging steps that I have taken so far:

- I uninstalled the global version as well as the extension, then reinstalled the extension and installed ESLint locally in the project folder.
- I am using a fresh install of an Angular app that was created using Angular `ng new` command.
- I ran `eslint --debug /Users/Yahia/Desktop/Plugngrow-UI/png-ui/.eslintrc.js` command. It results in no warnings other than a warning for ignoring the ".eslintrc.js" file while debugging.

Please note that ESLint works fine in another project which I downloaded from Angular docs while doing the introductory tutorial.

I have created a [Github repo](https://github.com/yahia91/eslint-vscode-angular-error-new) for the project if that helps with checking.

Please, excuse my novelty in programming and related tools.

Comment: Assuming you have that plugin in you `package.json` (as it is in you github repo), did you execute `npm install` to install a the needed plugins?

Comment: Yes, I did. I only got it to somehow work after installing specific old versions of Tslint@5.18 and Eslint@5.16. It is still giving me some occasional errors here and there and it is not functioning as the latest version of Eslint on the other project, but it is working somehow. I came to believe it is a problem with creating a new Angular app through the CLI as it installs Tslint as its linter and that was creating some sort of conflict I guess. I am not honestly sure.

Answer (score 4):

I just met with this problem yesterday.
I would suggest you reinstall "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin" locally and see that help. You can also have fresh setup of eslintrc.js file and should be easy to fix.

This link was helpful.
https://www.robertcooper.me/using-eslint-and-prettier-in-a-typescript-project